# No me deja crear un arreglo de tipo punto

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo en c++ y estoy intentando crear un arreglo de puntos, pero no logro hacerlo debido a que me salta error al declararlo

Punto.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#ifndef Punto_h
  #define Punto_h
    class Punto {
      public :
        Punto(float x, float y);
        float coordx()const;
        float coordy()const ;
        float distancia(const Punto & otroPunto) const;
        void trasladar(float x, float y);
        bool operator==(const Punto & otroPunto)const;
      private :
        float x;
        float y;
    };
#endif // Punto
```

Punto.cpp :

```
#include "Punto.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

Punto::Punto(float x,float y){
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y; }
float Punto :: coordx() const // supongo que tiene algun problema
 {
        return x ; }
float Punto :: coordy() const {
        return y ;}
float Punto :: distancia(const Punto & otroPunto)const{
        return sqrt(pow(x-otroPunto.x,2.0)+pow(y-otroPunto.y,2.0));}
void Punto :: trasladar(float x,float y){
        this -> x += x;
        this -> y += y; }
bool Punto :: operator==(const Punto & otroPunto)const{
        return(x==otroPunto.x)&&(y==otroPunto.y); }
```

Declaracion del arreglo:

```
Punto arreglo[100];
```

Aqui es donde esta el problema que no puedo identificar, desde ya mucha gracias por las respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu objeto `Punto` no tiene constructor por defecto, por ese motivo no sabe cómo construir los 100 elementos que le estás pidiendo, añádele un constructor por defecto y el error desaparecerá:

```
class Punto {
  public :
    Punto(); // constructor por defecto.
    Punto(float x, float y);
    float coordx()const;
    float coordy()const ;
    float distancia(const Punto & otroPunto) const;
    void trasladar(float x, float y);
    bool operator==(const Punto & otroPunto)const;
  private :
    float x;
    float y;
};
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Para hacer que tu objeto `Punto` se ajuste más a los estándares de C++ te aconsejo:

- Añade inicializadores a las variables miembro.
- Haz que el compilador genere el constructor por defecto.
- Usa la lista de inicialización.

```
class Punto {
  public :
    Punto() = default; // Constructor por defecto, generado por el compilador.
    Punto(float x, float y);
    float coordx()const;
    float coordy()const ;
    float distancia(const Punto & otroPunto) const;
    void trasladar(float x, float y);
    bool operator==(const Punto & otroPunto)const;
  private :
    float x = .0f; // Inicializador de variable miembro.
    float y = .0f; // Inicializador de variable miembro.
};

Punto::Punto(float x,float y) :
    x{x},
    y{y}
{}
```

Con estos cambios, al construir por defecto `Punto` todos sus elementos tendrán valor cero. En el caso del constructor con parámetros, la lista de inicialización no genera ambigüedad entre los argumentos `x` e `y` y las variables miembro `x` e `y`, ya que en ese contexto sólo se pueden poner variables miembro.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: +1 por una respuesta muy directa y completa y además consejos